# ¿Cómo asignar datos entre dos fechas?

Tags: javascript, json, array, jsonobject

Buen día amigos, tengo la siguiente duda

resulta que tengo el siguiente arreglo de objetos:

```
var array = [
         {
          fechas: "25-10",
          registros: 5
         },
          {
           fechas: "26-10",
           registros: 8
          },
           {
            fechas: "27-10",
            registros: 9
           },
           {
            fechas: "29-10",
            registros: 52
           }
    ];
```

El rango de estas fechas va desde 25-10 hasta el 29-10 como pueden observar queda faltando el 28-10, hay alguna manera de que pueda ingresar con registros en 0 lo que queden faltando dentro de determinado rango?

Es decir que queda de la sieguente manera:

```
 var array = [
         {
          fechas: "25-10",
          registros: 5
         },
          {
           fechas: "26-10",
           registros: 8
          },
           {
            fechas: "27-10",
            registros: 9
           },

           {
            fechas: "28-10",
            registros: 0
           },
           {
            fechas: "29-10",
            registros: 52
           }
    ];
```

Answer (score 0):

Cree un nuevo array apartir del primero recorriendolo y asignadole las nuevas fechas:

```js
var array1 = [
      {
          fechas: "25-10",
          registros: 5
         },
          {
           fechas: "26-10",
           registros: 8
          },
           {
            fechas: "27-10",
            registros: 9
           },
           {
            fechas: "29-10",
            registros: 52
           }
    ];

    let fechaAnterior = array1[0].fechas.split("-")
    var diaAnterior = parseInt(fechaAnterior[0]);
    var array2 = [];
    var registros = 1;

    array1.forEach((elemento,indice) => {

      let fecha = elemento.fechas.split("-");
      let dia = parseInt(fecha[0]);
      var diasFaltantes = (dia - diaAnterior);
      
      for(var i = diasFaltantes; i > 1; i--){
        var nuevoDia = (dia - i) + 1;
        array2.push({"fechas": nuevoDia+"-00","registros":0});
        registros++;
      }
      
      array2.push({"fecha": dia+"-10","registros":elemento.registros});
      
      registros++;
      diaAnterior = dia;
      
    });

    console.log(array2);
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, ¿exite la posibilidad de que queden los registros y los nuevos valores que entren queden en 0? Creo que tendía que modificar el for

Comment: @Venté listo ya lo modifique prueba

Comment: está súper tengo una duda, solo funcion para el mes 10? como haría para funcionara para dos fechas determinadas, es decir si el rango va desde 26-10 hasta el 01-11

Comment: Si desgraciadamente no funciona entre meses, hay que hacerle una adaptación